# Selenium IE Driver - code running on Chrome but not in IE

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, double-click

I am able to run below Selenium code on Chrome but not in IE. I wish to double click on the element populated in first row of dynamic table in webpage.

my code is :

```
    IWebElement xyz= webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphContent_fgFiles_gvResults']/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]"));
    Actions actionProvider = new Actions(webDriver);
    IAction contextClick = actionProvider.DoubleClick(xyz).Build();
    contextClick.Perform();
```

Comment: Please try using the equivalent CSS selector instead, sometimes IE does not recognise the xpath of an element.

Comment: I tried with the CSS selector and still no luck.

Comment: Is this a public website? Maybe i can try to figure out what's happening.

Comment: I tried debugging, and can see that in IE it is unable to find the element, though it is finding the element in Chrome.

Comment: Try writing a more dynamic xpath, though CSS selectors are more preferred performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
IAction contextClick = actionProvider.moveToElement(xyz).DoubleClick().Build();
```

instead of :

```
IAction contextClick = actionProvider.DoubleClick(xyz).Build();
```